# How we can use Authentication Provider in Visual force page?

Tags: visualforce, community, dynamic-visualforce, customer-community

I am using custom visual force page for Community self register and login. I want to add option for register and Login via Gmail and LinkedIn. I created two Authentication Providers and it is working from standard login page. How we can use that providers in our custom visual force page dynamically for any org?

Answer (score 2):

If you check the HTML source of the standard login page where Social Login button is present, you can see the following code.

[image]

In the JS the `useIdp` function is defined as below, which takes two arguments and updates the browser URL with the second parameter.

```
useIdp: function(a, b) {
    if (null !== l) try {
        l.setItem(n(), a)
    } catch (d) {}
    window.location.href = b
},
```

If you look look carefully at the URL, this nothing but the combination of Auth. Provider Salesforce Configuration URL and your community URL.

Decode this URL and you can see something like this, where `ccommunity` is my community name.

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/auth/sso/00Di0000000inohEAA/MyLinkedIn?community=https://xxxxxxxxxxx.na15.force.com/ccommunity&startURL=/ccommunity/
```

So in your VF page you can use this same URL in a anchor link to provide user to login via this Social Netowk. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for giving answer and appreciate your help. Problem is we are using custom Login and registration visual force page with custom UI so how we can get this URL? We can get this SSO Url from Auth. Providers but it would not same for all salesforce org.

Comment: You can get this URL from the standard login page. If you want to call the SSO methods directly from VF page then you have to implement the Registration Handler class. Check this link for details https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_linkedin.htm&language=en_US&type=0